# how to make hidden elements to pop up faster (jquery/ css)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, transition

I made a search panel which is hidden at page load. When the user clicks on the search icon, a popup appears (pop up) as a search form with a text box.
But with current codes, the way my search form popping up is very slow though I didn't add any transition to my css. Is there something wrong with below jQuery and not css problem?

```
  jQuery( ".search-icon" ).click(function() {    
    jQuery('.search-form').fadeIn(0);
    return false;   }); });

.search-form {
    display: none;
    clear: both;
    z-index: 2;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0; }
```

Comment: `jQuery('.search-form').show()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
jQuery(".search-icon").click(function() {
  jQuery('.search-form').toggle();
  return false;
});
```

```css
.search-form {
  display: none;
  clear: both;
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='search-icon'>icon</div>
<div class='search-form'>search form</div>
```

From [W3Schools.com *jQuery Effect fadeOut() Method*](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/eff_fadeout.asp):

> The fadeOut() method gradually changes the opacity, for selected elements, from visible to hidden (fading effect).
>
> ```
> $(selector).fadeOut(speed,easing,callback);
> ```

Comment: thank you so much. It works perfectly and what I wanted to do.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `show` instead of `fadeIn` if you don't need any animations and no-slowness.

```js
jQuery(".search-icon").click(function() {
  jQuery('.search-form').show();
  return false;
});
```

```css
.search-form {
  display: none;
  clear: both;
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='search-icon'>icon</div>
<div class='search-form'>search form</div>
```

Comment: Is there any way to add animations like fadeIn/ fadeOut but not very slow? When I tested fadeIn, the element (searchform) doesn't hide back when click the icon second time, and it has to.

Comment: To hide you need to use `fadeOut` and to make it fast, you can use `fadeIn('fast')`, similar goes for `fadeOut('fast')`

Comment: but fadeIn/ fadeOut doesn't hide the element (searchform) back, any ideas?

Comment: `fadeOut()` hides and `fadeIn()` shows the element.

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/); default value for fadIn is 400 milliseconds. You can either number or string statement (fast or slow). Try put number greater than 0, I guess jQuery itself assuming zero value equal as default parameter so it will given delay 400 ms.